# Why messages.blade.php is placed into master layout page rather than the page where I want redirect user to

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel as I was watching tutorials on Youtube. So, I have a question about why `messages.blade.php` file is included inside master layout page instead of the page where you want a user to redirect to and in that page you wanna show success message. Just imagine you have `store method` which creates new record and then insert it into database and after that you want to redirect user to, say, index page and in that page you want to show success message. So, is it ok if I include message only inside `index.blade.php` file

Comment: You can include it in anywhere

Comment: @ZainFarooq, yea I got but the author of tutorials I am watching said that "Yes it is ok to include messages file into index but the problem is we will have to include messages into every single view" the question comes WHY? Yes I have asked him but no answer at all received

Comment: Reuseability I guess. Putting it in the layout makes messages available to all views. If `index.blade.php` is the only page that needs those messages, no problem. If you have for example 12 forms that all need validation messages you'd need to include it in 12 files.

Comment: depends on are the message fix showing on the main layout, for example if the message always showing on the top, so you can in main layout include the message, but but what about in some view you want show the validation fail message under the <form> <input>, so you need on each sub-view include the message, so you can easy manage where you put the message to